# Apache Ignite as Hibernate L2 cache storing duplicate entities

Tags: java, hibernate, ignite

**Environment:**

- Vagrant running MySQL 5.6
- Java SE 1.8
- Hibernate 4.2.16.Final
- Apache Ignite 1.6

**Setup:**

- Entity ToggleSwitch with String id and State enum of On/Off
- Both equals() and hashcode() have been implemented against the id
- @Cache using READ_WRITE and default region
- Reader node performing EM.find() and displaying current State every second
- Writer node performing EM.find() and toggling State every 3 seconds
- Both nodes configured with TRANSACTIONAL atomicity, PARTITIONED cache mode, and FULL_SYNC write synchronization mode
- Uses TcpDiscoverySharedFsIpFinder for discovery

So the problem I'm running into is that the reader side is never picking up the changes from the writing side. I've dumped the contents of the cache (same frequency as the state) using IgniteInternalCache.entrySet(), and it shows two ToggleSwitch instances in the cache with identical keys.

I've tried adding them to a Set from the cached keys to see if that would produce the same results, but it acts as expected with only one instance being stored.

I have no idea at this point what's going on, any thoughts? Is it a bug or misconfiguration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely `equals` and/or `hashCode` are implemented incorrectly for the key. I would take these two keys stored in cache with their contents and try calling these methods to check if they are consistent or not.

**-- UPDATE --**

This issue can also occur in multi-application environment when the default binary marshaller is used. More details here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-3429

As a workaround, you can switch from the default binary serialization to `OptimizedMarhsaller` (see configuration sample below). This will force the key object to deserialize on the server side and properly apply custom `equals` logic.

```
<bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
    <property name="marshaller">
        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.marshaller.optimized.OptimizedMarshaller"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: The key is the CacheKey from Hibernate. They return true on `equals` and both return the same `hashcode`.

Comment: So I tried constructing the CacheKey directly `CacheKey cacheKey = new CacheKey("test", new StringNVarcharType(), ToggleSwitch.class.getName(), null, entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactoryImplementor.cass));` in both my reader and writer. Every time the writer writers to the cache, it writes a new key instead of writing over the existing one. The reading side always returns null. The reading side also grabs the `entrySet()` and dumps it the keys (1 for every write call), and shoves them into a `Set`. The `Set` only contains one key, so they are all equal.

Comment: @Spencer Do you have a test on GitHub or somewhere else?

Comment: I have a working example I can upload, but while I get that ready, I noticed that when dumping the full `entry` from the cache `entrySet` it showed that both entries had different `idHash` fields but the same `hash` fields for the `CacheKey`. Does this seem correct?

Comment: https://github.com/shaan-axonify/ignite-l2-example

Run ReaderMain, then WriterMain, then CacheDumpMain. Reader just spits out the entity, Writer increments a counter on the entity, and CacheDump just shows what's in the cache based on the `IgniteInternalCache.entrySet`. I used Derby as the DB.

Comment: @Spencer Thanks for the test! I reproduced the issue and got to the bottom of it. See the update in the response.

Comment: @Spencer Where you able to resolve getting EmbeddedId / IdClass working?  I am having issues described in this link: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-3429

Comment: @ChristianMatthew I'm assuming you are running this as a cluster? I ran into this with query caching, myself, as we don't use embedded ids. The solution is to set the name for your SessionFactory. Deserialization does a lookup in a SessionFactory registry using the UUID for local factories and the name for remote factories.

Set session_factory_name and if you're not using JNDI session_factory_is_jndi to false as well.

Here are some relevant links I stumbled across:
https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/pull/820
https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HB-178

Comment: Here are some more if you're interested: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9424 and https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6822

Comment: @Spencer for youre reply but still having issues. set "hibernate.session_factory_name" = hibernate_sf_starguest, "hibernate.ejb.entitymanager_factory_name (just in case" = hibernate_sf_starguest, "hibernate.session_factory_name_is_jndi": Error is:
Caused by: java.io.InvalidObjectException: Could not find a SessionFactory [uuid=93176b36-136d-4ff1-a70b-a308fbf320f1,name=hibernate_sf_starguest]
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.locateSessionFactoryOnDeserialization(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1781)
 at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.readResolve(SessionFactoryImpl.java:1761)

Comment: @ChristianMatthew Sorry, I missed this response... I'm not sure this will be relevant anymore, but are you running 2+ nodes? I found that stack trace, for me, was being produced by the remote node and then logged on the calling node. If so are all nodes configured to have a SessionFactory with those settings? Do you have more than one SessionFactory backed by the same Ignite node?